# Insert in one table and delete from another simultaneously

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert, sql-delete

```
<?php
include("conn.php");
?>
<?php
$name=$_POST['name']; 
$fathers_name=$_POST['fathers_name'];
$gotra=$_POST['gotra'];
$image=$_POST['image'];
$village=$_POST['village'];
$company_name=$_POST['company_name'];
$address1=$_POST['address1'];
$address2=$_POST['address2'];
$city=$_POST['city'];
$pincode=$_POST['pincode'];
$mobile1=$_POST['mobile1'];
$mobile2=$_POST['mobile2'];
$village_number=$_POST['village_number'];
if($_POST['add2'])
{
$i=mysql_query("insert into members_data values(NULL,'".$name."','".$fathers_name."','".$gotra."','".$image."','".$village."','".$company_name."','".$address1."','".$address2."','".$city."','".$pincode."','".$mobile1."','".$mobile2."','".$village_number."')");

$res=mysql_query("SELECT image FROM temp_members_data WHERE 'image' = '$image'");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($res);
mysql_query("DELETE FROM temp_members_data WHERE 'image' = '$image'");


}
?>


<script type="text/javascript">window.location="admin_approve.php"</script>
```

I need help in inserting in one table and deleting from another table by clicking just add button.  Its like adding in main table and deleting from the temp table. Please Help

Comment: must do some research on queries..then post at stack

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Answer (score 0):

"You must have 50 reputation to comment" >.<

Are you wanting to move this data from one table to another table? From on database to another database? You need to clarify a little bit more on what you are trying to do. Do you have some kind of primary key that you use instead of using an image? (or rather image patch). From my understanding you want to move it from one table to another. If this is the case: Do you NEED to delete that data in `temp_members_data` or would that just be something that would be nice to have? If it's the latter, then try this:

`INSERT INTO new_members_data SELECT * FROM old_members_data WHERE image = '$image'"`

Comment: no i dont want to move I want to delete from the old table. I have called the data of temp_members_data to a form and when the admin clicks on the add button it should insert in the new table and also delete from the old table. id is the primary key but it is on a autofill mode.

Comment: I would try doing it in a if statement. I would also recommend using mysqli or PDO (I prefer PDO) as mysql_* functions are deprecated in php5. (Refer to chinna's comment) But something along the lines of `if { "insert query into new database" "delete info from old database"